# Find publicly traded stocks that replicate return of private asset

Tags: stocks, etf

I have a set of historical returns for a private or thinly traded asset. The returns are within normal market ranges (i.e. *not* 2002 era Google). I'd like to build a portfolio of ETF's or stocks that have a high correlation with the return of the private asset. Ideally this would be something along the lines of the interface offered by similarstocks.com. If necessary I can guess at a basket of ETF's that would most closely match but I don't know the weights, or which particular stocks in the basket would provide the best correlation.

What's the best way to do this? Is there an online tool?

Comment: Questions seeking product/service recommendations are specifically off-topic. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Your question implies a top-down approach to finding these correlated assets i.e. look at the entire universe of stocks, and find something...anything publicly traded with the best correlation. (To directly answer your question, I don't know of a tool to do this other than manually)

Over any period of time, it is possible that two assets with very businesses and exogenous market forces could display high correlation. Using one to hedge or track the other would be a severe mistake as divergence could occur just as randomly as the previous correlation. For example, if i had data on thousands of stocks and unleashed some quants and high powered computing on it to find correlations, i might find that a blank check company's stock is highly correlated to Walmart. Does this mean i should use one to hedge/track the other? No.

I would suggest you consider a bottom-up approach of defining a smaller universe of potentially correlated assets using the value-defining qualities of your private asset as eligibility parameters, and do some very manual work determining why/how/when/if they are correlated. When that correlation breaks down mid-trade (as it most often does with fancy hedges/tracking), you want to know why, if its temporary, or if you were wrong and need to pull the plug.